# How spring-data-cassandra handle connection pooling?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Can you please tell me how spring-data-cassandra handle connection pooling? I am usring spring-data-cassandra 1.5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Spring Data Cassandra documentations Java Configuration section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html#cassandra-connectors.javaconfig), there is an example of a Java-based configuration, which creates a [`CassandraClusterFactoryBean` where you can set `PoolingOptions`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/cassandra/config/CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean.html#setPoolingOptions-com.datastax.driver.core.PoolingOptions-)

[`PoolingOptions` is a class from the DataStax driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html), and [its usage is described in the documentation of the driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/pooling/).

Comment: Thanks Jens, u save my day :)

Comment: `CassandraClusterFactoryBean` and `PoolingOptionsFactoryBean` have been removed from SDC. Is there any other way to get/set the pooling options? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435926/get-set-poolingoptions-in-spring-data-cassanda-boot