# Get/Set PoolingOptions in Spring-Data-Cassanda (boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, connection-pooling, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using the following dependencies in my environment:

- spring-boot-starter-parent - v2.3.5.RELEASE
- spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra - same
- cassandra-driver-core (com.datastax.cassandra) - v3.2.0

How do I get access to the connection pooling options set in `com.datastax.driver.core.PoolingOptions` in my setup?

Spring Data Cassandra (SDC) docs specify the below:

> AbstractCassandraConfiguration lets you provide various configuration
> options, such as initial entities, default query options, pooling
> options, socket options, and many more.

But I can't, for the life of me, find where to set these pooling options set in the DS Driver:(

It looks like `CassandraClusterFactoryBean` and `PoolingOptionsFactoryBean` in Spring data Cassandra have been removed and I do not understand how to get a handle of the `PoolingOptions` without these or through the `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` extension/impl that I wrote.

Below are supposed to be the supported pooling options. But how do I get access to the `PoolingOptions` bean that holds these configs in the code?

```
Connection pooling options

cassandra.pool.heartbeat-interval-seconds - heartbeat interval in seconds.
cassandra.pool.idle-timeout-seconds - idle connection timeout in seconds.
cassandra.pool.pool-timeout-millis - timeout for acquiring connection from pool in ms.

cassandra.pool.local.core-connections-per-host - initial number of connections to each "local" host.
cassandra.pool.local.max-connections-per-host - max number of connections to each "local" host.
cassandra.pool.local.max-requests-per-connection - max number of requests per connections to "local" host.
cassandra.pool.local.new-connection-threshold - threshold to trigger new connection to "local" host.

cassandra.pool.remote.core-connections-per-host - initial number of connections to each "remote" host.
cassandra.pool.remote.max-connections-per-host - max number of connections to each "remote" host.
cassandra.pool.remote.max-requests-per-connection - max number of requests per connections to "remote" host.
cassandra.pool.remote.new-connection-threshold - threshold to trigger new connection to "remote" host.
```

It's also mentioned in the SDC docs that:

> DataStax Java Driver 4 merges `Cluster` and `Session` objects into a
> single `CqlSession` object, therefore, all Cluster-related API was
> removed.

> To reflect the change in configuration builders,
> `ClusterBuilderConfigurer` was renamed to `SessionBuilderConfigurer`
> accepting now `CqlSessionBuilder` instead of the `Cluster.Builder`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How I managed to get access to those configs is by overriding the **cassandraDriverConfigLoader** bean from the **CassandraAutoConfiguration** class.

Here in the **cassandraDriverConfigLoader** bean the Spring configs are mapped to Cassandra driver configs.

Basically I copy-pasted the code from the auto-configuration into my project and added the needed configs. There is a handy Enum with all the needed configs.

```
@Bean
public DriverConfigLoader cassandraDriverConfigLoader(CassandraProperties properties,
        ObjectProvider<DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer> builderCustomizers) {
    .....
}

private Config cassandraConfiguration(CassandraProperties properties) {
    CassandraDriverOptions options = new CassandraDriverOptions();
    options.add(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_MAX_REQUESTS,30000)
    ...
}
```

To verify if my custom configs were loaded I just put a breakpoint here **DriverConfig.getDefaultProfile**